# How do I write a template tag that shows if a user belongs to an app when that app isn't part of the context?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have an app that has a FK to USER.

In ALL templates I need a template tag that tests to see if the logged in user is in that app.

For instance...

On every page I want to show a template block if the user is in the customer.approved set.

I've been playing with {% if approved in customer.approved %} - but I'm not getting anywhere.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: When you say app, you mean a model right? An application is a set of models, views, urls .. and a model is a class

Comment: Ok, so my post below should be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a filter, that checks if user is in your model (FK). So in your application_tags.py, you would do something like:

```
from django import template
from app.models import MyModel

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def belongs_to_app(user):
    if user.is_authenticated(): # Could be AnonymousUser
        try:
            # Check if there is a object with FK to logged user
            m = MyModel.objects.get(user=user)
            return True
        except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            return False
    return False
```

And in your template:

```
{% if user|belongs_to_app %}
 ....
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

if yo set user perms you can write a context_processor so that:

```
def user_is_authorised(request):
    if request.user.has_perm('myapp.can_view'):
        return {'approved' : True}
    else:
        return {'approved' : False}
```

& include this in the CONTEXT_PROCESSORS settings.py tuple as 'myapp.context_processors.py'

more reading at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#handling-object-permissions &
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth

alternatively you can set the application in a session variable and then check this against your customer approved foreign key.

Comment: `return {'approved': request.user.has_perm('myapp.can_view')}`